# update symfony 4.3 to 4.4 Call to undefined method phpDocumentor\Reflection\DocBlock\Tags\InvalidTag::getType()

Tags: php, symfony

I get error

```
[php] Call to undefined method phpDocumentor\Reflection\DocBlock\Tags\InvalidTag::getType() ["exception" => Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError { …}]
```

after upgrade Symfony 4.3 to 4.4

here is composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.4",
    "ext-bcmath": "*",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-dom": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "ext-openssl": "*",
    "ext-simplexml": "*",
    "ext-soap": "*",
    "ext-sodium": "*",
    "beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "^1.2",
    "codeception/codeception": "^4.0",
    "codeception/module-webdriver": "^1.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.12.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^2.1",
    "excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle": "^1.5",
    "friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle": "^2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "2.2",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.4",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^2.1",
    "geocoder-php/google-maps-provider": "^4.2",
    "happyr/google-analytics-bundle": "^5.0",
    "helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle": "^9.0",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.1",
    "jeremy-dunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper": "^2.6",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "^2.4",
    "jms/translation-bundle": "^1.4",
    "knplabs/doctrine-behaviors": "^1.5",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "^2.2",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.5",
    "lcobucci/jwt": "^3.3",
    "liip/imagine-bundle": "^2.1",
    "meenie/javascript-packer": "1.1",
    "monext/payline-sdk": "dev-master",
    "moneyphp/money": "v3.1.3",
    "natxet/CssMin": "v3.0.6",
    "nesbot/carbon": "^2.1",
    "nikic/php-parser": "4.0.3",
    "nyholm/psr7": "^1.2",
    "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "^1.14",
    "payum/core": "^1.5",
    "payum/offline": "^1.5",
    "payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp": "^1.5",
    "payum/payum-bundle": "^2.3",
    "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^1.1",
    "php-http/httplug-bundle": "^1.18",
    "php-translation/symfony-bundle": "^0.8.0",
    "secit-pl/imap-bundle": "^1.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.2",
    "sg/datatablesbundle": "^v1.0",
    "shippo/shippo-php": "1.*",
    "sirprize/postal-code-validator": "^1.3",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "3.55.0",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.6",
    "sonata-project/page-bundle": "^3.9",
    "sonata-project/translation-bundle": "^2.4",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^4.2",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.3",
    "symfony/acl-bundle": "^1.0",
    "symfony/asset": "^4.4",
    "symfony/console": "^4.4",
    "symfony/expression-language": "^4.4",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
    "symfony/form": "^4.4",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.4",
    "symfony/http-client": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/mercure-bundle": "^0.2.3",
    "symfony/messenger": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/mime": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.3",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/process": "^4.4",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "^4.4",
    "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.2",
    "symfony/translation": "^4.4",
    "symfony/validator": "^4.4",
    "symfony/web-link": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.6",
    "symfony/yaml": "^4.4",
    "tbbc/money-bundle": "^3.1",
    "vendus/vendus-sdk-php": "^1.0",
    "vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.8",
    "white-october/pagerfanta-bundle": "^1.2",
    "willdurand/geocoder-bundle": "^5.1"
},


"require-dev": {
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "^4.4",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.7",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/test-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/var-dumper": "^4.4",
    "symfony/web-server-bundle": "^4.4"
},



 "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": true,
            "require": "4.4.*"
        },
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": null
    }
```

Any suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found a temporary fix

```
composer require phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock:4.3.4
```

solution from here

https://gitmemory.com/merguezzz?fbclid=IwAR3isWBoCTODIuAxh-hMKP5tRRiMujXRBSbb60u1UzX0dZwDHuXEd_zspIo